# Función PHP retorna valores diferentes en Local y en el hosting

Tags: php

Tengo una función PHP que en local me retorna un resultado y en el hosting me retorno otro diferente, el resultado que me devuelve en el hosting es el verdadero.

```
<?php
function hexTo32Float($strHex) {
    $v = hexdec($strHex);
    $x = ($v & ((1 << 23) - 1)) + (1 << 23) * ($v >> 31 | 1);
    $exp = ($v >> 23 & 0xFF) - 127;
    return $x * pow(2, $exp - 23)*($v>>31==0?1:-1);
  }
//example
echo hexTo32Float("c1c64247").PHP_EOL; 
echo hexTo32Float("c282d9c2").PHP_EOL;
```

Esta es la función alguien sabe si se deberá a alguna configuración de PHP que me devuelve resultados diferentes ?

Comment: ¿Qué retorna en local y qué retorna en el hosting?

Comment: en local 7.2176380157471       62.574691772461, en el hosting  -24.782361984253 -65.425308227539

Comment: tanto el hosting como mi maquina local usamos windows de 64 bits, me podrias ayudar a resolverlo?